# Query to fetch records only Oracle and Java

Tags: sql

I have the below table :

Employee table :

```
Id   skillset

1    O
2    J
2    O
3    J
4    J
4    O 
5    O
5    J
5    U
```

I want a query to get only the employes those skill sets are O and J ( Oracle and java )
and that means only 2 and 4 and not even 5 bex it has skill set unix.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `GROUP BY`. With `HAVING` make sure there are two different skillset values for an id, and that no other values that O and J are there:

```
select id
from tablename
group by id
having count(distinct skillset) = 2
   and count(case when skillset not in ('O','J') then 1 end) = 0
```